# SharedPreference StringSet to Array Order Issue

Tags: android, arrays, set, android-sharedpreferences

Please be patient while I explain my issue:

1) I am storing my preferences via a StringSet as follows:

```
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            // Create a new Arraylist with the details of our details
            ArrayList <String> newCityFareDetails = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Store various values
            newCityFareDetails.add(0, String.valueOf(cloneFare.value1()));
            newCityFareDetails.add(1, String.valueOf(cloneFare.value2()));
            newCityFareDetails.add(2, String.valueOf(cloneFare.value3()));
            newCityFareDetails.add(3, String.valueOf(cloneFare.value4()));
            newCityFareDetails.add(4, cloneFare.value5());

            // Only value 5 is a string, rest are all floats


            // Convert to a hashstring, give it the name of our value
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            set.addAll(newCityFareDetails);
            editor.putStringSet(extras.getString("startCity"), set);

            // And write it to storage
            editor.commit();
```

Now, I'm trying to read it as follows:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Set<String> tryCityFromPrefs = prefs.getStringSet(currentCity, null);

 if (tryCityFromPrefs!=null){


                        // Crude code, but we convert the preferences into a String array
                        String[] values = tryCityFromPrefs.toArray(new String[tryCityFromPrefs.size()]);

                        myFare = new Fare(Float.parseFloat(values[0]), Float.parseFloat(values[1]),
                                Float.parseFloat(values[2]), Float.parseFloat(values[3]), values[4]);

                    }
```

Now, problem is that the myFare is not getting initialized properly because the values in the array are scrambled. i.e. the String value that was at the last position when we save is now in the 2nd position. Is this something to do with Sets to String conversion? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set` does not guarantee order. While there are specific `Set` implementations (e.g., `LinkedHashSet`) that are ordered, that's not what `SharedPreferences` uses.

Your options are:

1. Change your app to not care about the order.
2. Save the data in `SharedPreferences` some other way. In [this app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor), for example, I use `JsonReader`/`JsonWriter` to save an `ArrayList` into a single `String` value.
3. Save the data in some other fashion (e.g., JSON file, SQLite database with a sequence number to maintain order).

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on how ArrayList can be written and read into a JSON with some code example? Also is this issue occuring during saving the pref or reading from it?

Comment: @zooter: "can you elaborate a bit on how ArrayList can be written and read into a JSON with some code example?" -- I pointed you to a sample app. [Here is the specific file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/tte/EditHistory.java) -- see the `openEditors()` and `saveEditors()` methods. "Also is this issue occuring during saving the pref or reading from it?" -- I have no idea. It could be both.